# Name of Blunt Tip Sheet Metal Screw

Tags: screws

I was replacing the heating element on my old Jenn-Air and I lost an important screw. It is a #8 3/8" long *blunt-tip* hex head screw holding two pieces of sheet metal together. The head fits a 1/4" socket.

Does this type of screw have a name?

Worst case, I will find a sharp-point sheet metal screw and grind off the tip. I can't see what is on the other side, but it might be important not to penetrate too far.

A hex head is desired since they are fairly inaccessible (without further disassembly).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around some more, I found the answer to my own question.

The screw itself doesn't have a name (other than *sheet metal*), but there are several *types* of points. I want a type B.

[image]

http://www.engineeredpartsinc.com/pdf/screw-point-types.pdf

Amazon has a type B, Home Depot doesn't, but I can probably improvise. If I can't get something from Home Depot to work, I will order from Amazon and wait another day.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a Hex head #8 3/8"  sheet  metal screw.

Take your photo with you to the hardware store and find one.

I am not sure that having a blunt tip is a necessity. It is ?

Maybe you can steal one from elsewhere on the unit where it is not critical.